# Adding constant to the variable in a Limsup

Tags: calculus

Let $f(t)$ be a real valued function and $C$ a constant. Is it true that

$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t+C)}{t} ?
$$

I have tried to prove it using a change of variable $s=t+C$, but the denominator seems problematic.

Comment: Why does the denominator seem problematic? $t-C\to \infty$ as $t\to\infty$,

Comment: Because when I substitute I no longer have $t$ on the denominator but $t-C$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{f(t+C)}{t}=\frac{f(t+C)}{t+C}\,\frac{t+C}{t}.
$$

Comment: THank you! I have been able to come up with a proof using this. This is a very clever trick.